# IMAP and PHP on CentOS

Tags: php, imap, centos

I'm trying to install imap on CentOS but it's not working.

I did:

yum install php-imap

it was installed. Then I enabled on php.ini the extension = php_imap.dll

I have also restarted httpd many times, including using 'graceful'.

But it's not working. phpinfo() is not showing it and the scripts that need it are not working. I'm also pretty noob when it comes to Linux, so I'm sure this is some little thing I'm missing because of my ignorance :)

Any ideas? I'm following all tutorials around but I don't know why it's not working.

Thank you!!!

Comment: This question probably should be in ServerFault

Comment: Any ideas?

------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------

Comment: I've converted the above 'answer' to a comment, this is not a chat room, answers are for answers, comments are for comments - also posting lines like you did above is highly unlikely to help - please read our FAQ.

Comment: the line is because there is a character limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your php.ini instead. The .dll extension is for windows:

```
extension = php_imap.so
```

What PHP RPMs are you using? Normally they'll stick their own ini file in /etc/php.d and restarting httpd is all you have to do. Does /etc/php.d/imap.ini exist? If you've mixed up different PHP RPMs or compiled stuff from source, that might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I found imap.ini, it reads extension=imap.so. What can I do now? Should I still modify my php.ini? I tried but nothing happened, restarted apache and still not working. Also, extension_dir in php.ini is empty, even though phpinfo gives me a path anyways: "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613" What can I do? When I go to this path I only see ffmpeg.so. Thank you!!

Comment: I tried moving imap.so to that folder but still not working...